# ¿Cómo llamar un fichero b.rb con código, ejecutándolo desde un fichero a.rb en ruby?

Tags: ruby

En el fichero de texto `a.rb` tengo el código:

```
print "hello"
```

y en el fichero de texto `b.rb` tengo el código:

```
print "world"
```

¿Cómo haría:

```
print "hello"
exec b.rb
```

para que me apareciera `hello world` combinando ambos ficheros de texto?

Answer (score 1):

Para cargar un archivo de texto externo se utiliza [`load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load).

En tu caso, bastaría con tener lo siguiente en `a.rb`:

```
print "hello"
load "b.rb"
```

Dando como resultado:

```
helloworld
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo mediante un `require b.rb` en tu archivo 'a.rb', o como bien te comentan mediante un `load b.rb`. La diferencia entre “load” vs “require”, es que load reprocesa el código cada vez que es llamado y require solo lo procesa una vez. Ej. a.rb => `require 'b.rb' 
var_1 = "hola"
puts var_1 + " " + var_2`  b.rb => `var_2 = "mundo"`